# C output differ with the same code

Tags: c++, c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int* a[10];
    int* p = a;
    int i = 0;
    for (p = &a[0], i = 0; p < &a[10]; p++, i++)
    {
        *p = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

the output on GCC using eclipse:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

the output using visual studio:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

why ?

Comment: C != C++. Choose one!

Comment: and what do eclipse and visual studio have to do with this? Can you please add _only_ the relevant tags

Comment: `int* p = a;`..compiler din;t scream?

Comment: would expect the compiler would throw up several warnings and errors with this code

Comment: I would bet that one is a 32 bit compiler and the other is 64. And neither is compiling with warnings enabled so they didn't scream about how broken the code is.

Comment: `a[10]` breaks array bounds.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Indeed but the compiler is required to interpret &a[10] as a + 10, and reading that *pointer* is valid as it's one past the end.

Comment: @WeatherVane one off pointers are fine.

Comment: Of course, the code is `&a[10]` not `a[10]`

Comment: yes it has a lot of warning but no errors. @ChrisTurner

Comment: You can use this code to check for C compliance. If it compiles, your compiler is non-compliant. In case of gcc, make sure to compile the code as standard C: `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: If the compiler screams a warning at you, you should listen and solve the problem. You should not just ignore it.

Comment: @Art, I would expect the compiler has 32 bit integers but 64 bit addresses.

Comment: @MuhammadEssam just because something is a *warning* doesn't mean that the code is good. You need to address the warnings. You cannot ignore them. They can be indicators of bugs, which is why the warnings are there.

Comment: Almost all of the warnings are serious errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is declared as an array of 10 pointers to `int`. `a` in `int* p = a;` will decay to `int **`, but `p` is of type `int *`. Compiler will raise a warning about incompatible pointer assignment. You need to change the declaration

```
int* a[10];
```

to

```
int a[10];
```

This program invokes undefined behavior, so strange things can happen.

Comment: i see. you are right. but why the output is different ?

Comment: @MuhammadEssam; It's because undefined behavior.

Comment: @MuhammadEssam Undefined means that the result it not defined. Do not expect anything that  is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

```
% gcc error.c -Wall -Wextra
error.c: In function ‘main’:
error.c:7:14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     int* p = a;
              ^
error.c:9:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     for (p = &a[0], i = 0; p < &a[10]; p++, i++)
            ^
error.c:9:30: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
     for (p = &a[0], i = 0; p < &a[10]; p++, i++)
                              ^
error.c:15:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%d\n", a[i]);
                  ^
```

Hint:

```
int a[10]; // notice the lack of star here.
```

Comment: Generally we would complain about code only or snippet only answers. But this. . .can't be any more clear.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya it's got the solution now too :D